# SQL fails to deliver expected result with CASE WHEN ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

What i wanted to do is something like this:
If this product is discounted, check if promotionType is 0 and discountMethod is 0 and print out directDiscount(category). If not, check if promotionType is 0 and discountMethod is 1. Print out directDiscount(percentage), or else check if promotionType is 1 and then print out quantityBasedDiscount. **If all of them fail, print out basePrice(no promotions) instead. Which is where the product is not discounted.**

I tried to run my code. All seems to work well. But sql fails to print out **basePrice(no promotions)**, which is when the product is not on discount.

Is there something wrong with the handling of my `CASE WHEN` method?

```sql
DECLARE @productname VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @productname = 'Earth Choice Wool & Delicates Liquid Detergent - Eucalyptus Fresh'

SELECT
  product.productName,
  price.basePrice AS nettPrice,

-- column indicating the effective result type:
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT productName FROM discount WHERE productName = @productname) THEN 
        CASE
          WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 0 THEN 'directDiscount(currency)'
          WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 1 THEN 'directDiscount(percentage)'
          WHEN discount.promotionType = 1 THEN 'quantityBasedDiscount'
        END
    ELSE 'base price (no promotions)'
  END AS calculationResultType

FROM
  product
  INNER JOIN price ON price.productName = product.productName
  INNER JOIN discount ON price.productName = discount.productName

WHERE product.productName = @productname;
```

Comment: You do an INNER JOIN on the discount table on the productName, so if the productName doesn't exist in your discount table this JOIN will filter out that row.  So the EXISTS condition can never be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch your inner joins with left joins, like this:

```
DECLARE @productname VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @productname = 'Earth Choice Wool & Delicates Liquid Detergent - Eucalyptus Fresh'

SELECT
  product.productName,
  price.basePrice AS nettPrice,

-- column indicating the effective result type:
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT productName FROM discount WHERE productName = @productname) THEN 
        CASE
          WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 0 THEN 'directDiscount(currency)'
          WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 1 THEN 'directDiscount(percentage)'
          WHEN discount.promotionType = 1 THEN 'quantityBasedDiscount'
        END
    ELSE 'base price (no promotions)'
  END AS calculationResultType

FROM
  product
  LEFT JOIN price ON price.productName = product.productName
  LEFT JOIN discount ON price.productName = discount.productName

WHERE product.productName = @productname;
```

Comment: the subquery is probably not necessary, you already have the row from `discount` with the same selection on `productname`